# MySQL Query to get Time Before and After specified Time

Tags: mysql

I am looking to pull data from my database for a time interval of 90 Minutes (before and after) a specified date and time. Currently I am using below query but it's returning zero records. Please help me in doing this.

```
SELECT *
FROM `ashwani_video_user_tbl`
WHERE `assigned_date`
BETWEEN from_unixtime( 1324363500 ) - INTERVAL 120
MINUTE AND from_unixtime( 1324363500 ) + INTERVAL 120
MINUTE
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **[DATE_ADD](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp)** and **[DATE_SUB](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_sub.asp)**

```
SELECT *
FROM `ashwani_video_user_tbl`
WHERE `assigned_date` BETWEEN 
                       DATE_SUB(from_unixtime(1324363500), INTERVAL 90 MINUTE) 
                       AND 
                       DATE_ADD(from_unixtime(1324363500), INTERVAL 90 MINUTE)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

[*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6861a/8)

Comment: I used same Query but still it showing zero results. assigned_date is a Timestamp and contains data in YYYY-mm-dd h:i:s format.

Comment: can you post the schema and your sample records so i can test it on sqlfiddle? :)

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ashwani_video_user_tbl` (
  `id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `assigned_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `view_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `video_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `ashwani_video_user_tbl` (`id`, `user_id`, `assigned_date`, `view_status`, `video_name`) VALUES
(38, 10, '2012-08-20 19:00:00', 1, 'art-n-fine-art-A.flv'),
(36, 8, '2012-08-20 19:00:00', 1, 'art-n-fine-art-A.flv');

Comment: from your example condition, the unix timestamp is equivalent to `December, 19 2011 22:45:00` so 90 minutes before and after is `December, 19 2011 21:15:00` and `December, 20 2011 00:15:00` respectively. Obviously, `August, 20 2012 19:00:00` is not selected because its not within the range.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM `ashwani_video_user_tbl`
WHERE `assigned_date`
BETWEEN  1324363500 - 60*90   AND  1324363500 + 60*90
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

90 - is number of minutes, you can change this value.